# How do I print a return statement from another class?

Tags: java, methods, return

I've got a class called `Files` where I have a `toString` method like so:

```
     public String toString() {
        String res = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i) {
            if (i > 0) {
                res += " ";
            }
            res += files.get(i);
        }
        return res + "]";
     }
```

In a separate class called `Homework` I have another toString method where I am trying to print the string that was returned in `Files.toString()`. Right now my code looks like:

```
    public String toString(){
        String output = Files.toString();
        return output;

    }
```

But the error it's giving me is that it can't make a static reference to a non static method. Is there a way to make a non static reference? Both `toString` methods are not static so I don't know why it is making a static reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expresson

```
   Files.toString()
```

refers to a static `toString` method - you need to use an instance of `Files`

```
Files files = new Files();
```

...

```
String output = files.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `toString` in `Files` is not a static method but you're referencing it in a static way. Make an object of `Files` and then access it like `new Files().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

you want to use a files object not the Files class, the way you do it you call the method toString() from the class File wich you can't do because toString is not a static method, but you can call toString from an object based on the Files class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a static reference:

```
Files.toString()
```

Because `Files` is the name of the class.  However, this is not a static method:

```
public String toString() {
```

If you're trying to call `.toString()` on a specific *instance* of `Files` then you need to call it on that instance, not on the class itself.  For example, if the instance variable is called `myFiles` then you'd do this:

```
public String toString(){
    String output = myFiles.toString();
    return output;
}
```

Where is your instance of `Files` in your `Homework` object?  Or, if you don't have an instance, what are you trying to turn into a string?

Comment: That must be where my problem lies. I haven't made an instance yet >.<

Comment: @Drieke: From the structure it seems like somewhere in that `Homework` object there would be such an instance, probably at the class level.  You'll need to create the variable first before you can do write any code that uses it, otherwise the Java code won't compile.  (As opposed to looser interpreted languages, which would otherwise fail at runtime when trying to reference a non-existant variable.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an instance of Files class to be able to invoke it's non-static method.

```
Files f = new Files();
f.toString();
```